# Generate buckets of a numerical variable using interquartile range in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data stored in my pandas dataframe that shows salary for a bunch of users and their category.

```
| category | user_id   | salary |
|----------|-----------|--------|
| A        | 546457568 | 49203  |
| C        | 356835679 | 49694  |
| A        | 356785637 | 48766  |
| B        | 45668758  | 36627  |
| C        | 686794    | 59508  |
| C        | 234232376 | 32765  |
| C        | 4356345   | 44058  |
| A        | 9878987   | 9999999|
```

What i would like to do is generate a new column `salary_bucket` that shows a bucket for salary, that is determined from the upper/lower limits of the Interquartile range for salary.
e.g. calculate upper/lower limits according to `q1 - 1.5 x iqr` and `q3 + 1.5 x iqr`, then  split this into 10 equal buckets and assign each row to the relevant bucket based on salary. I know from exploration that there is no data outside the lower limit , but for data above the upper limit I would like a seperate bucket such as `outside_iqr`.

In the end I would liek to get something like so:

```
| category | user_id   | salary | salary_bucket |
|----------|-----------|--------|---------------|
| A        | 546457568 | 49203  | 7             |
| C        | 356835679 | 49694  | 7             |
| A        | 356785637 | 48766  | 7             |
| B        | 45668758  | 36627  | 3             |
| C        | 686794    | 59508  | 5             |
| C        | 234232376 | 32765  | 3             |
| C        | 4356345   | 44058  | 4             |
| A        | 9878987   | 9999999|outside_iqr    |
```

(these buckets are not actually calculate just for illustration sake)

Is something like `qcut` useful here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) to turn *continuous data* into *categorical data*.

```
# First, we need to calculate our IQR.
q1 = df.salary.quantile(0.25)                 
q3 = df.salary.quantile(0.75)
iqr = q3 - q1

# Now let's calculate upper and lower bounds.
lower = q1 - 1.5*iqr
upper = q3 + 1.5*iqr

# Let us create our bins:
num_bins = 10
bin_width = (upper - lower) / num_bins
bins = [lower + i*bin_width for i in range(num_bins)]
bins += [upper, float('inf')]  # Now we add our last bin, which will contain any value greater than the upper-bound of the IQR.

# Let us create our labels:
labels = [f'Bucket {i}' for i in range(1,num_bins+1)]
labels.append('Outside IQR')

# Finally, we add a new column to the df:
df['salary_bucket'] = pd.cut(df.salary, bins=bins, labels=labels)
```

So basically, you'll need to generate your own list of buckets and labels according to what you require, and then pass those as arguments to `pandas.cut`.